# Flash game app sounds keep playing when closed

Tags: android, flash, webview

I made an android app that has a webview which loads a flash game from assets folder.
Evertything is working except when I leave the game the sound keeps going on. I tried to finish the activity on pressing back button, but it is the same.

```
package com.example.flashgame;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.swf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that while you may have called `finish()`, the garbage collector doesn't necessarily collect your Activity straight away, which would result in the objects you've created (such as any `MediaPlayer` objects or similar) hanging around for a while - which includes your `WebView`.

The issue is normally that people need to call `stop()` or similar on your flash game/audio objects before you call 'finish()', which will result in them actually stopping rather than hanging around in the system waiting for them to be garbage collected. In your case, you'll probably need to load a `null` url into your webview or similar to stop the flash game from running